# ASP.NET Core 2.1 WebApi роутинг

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Вот такая вот ошибка у меня:
Request matched multiple actions resulting in ambiguity. Matching actions: AOO.microservice.Controllers.QuotesController.Get (AOO.microservice)

Я хочу использовать два разных эндпойнта:
1. /aoo-api/quotes
2. /aoo-api/quotes?pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}

в коде соответственно два метода

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
```

и

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] string pageNumber, [FromQuery] string pageSize)
```

Насколько я понимаю, система не отличает иди роуты и считает их одинаковыми, но ведь метода разные и параметры другие.
Есть-ли какие варианты обойти эту проблему(не переименовывая действия и не меняя роуты)?

Comment: По-моему, не получится сделать, как вы хотите. Вроде бы стандартным способом является проверка входных параметров - и если они равны null - выполняете одни действия, не равны - другие действия.

Comment: вы совершенно правы, я переопределил атрибут стандартной проверки. Теперь все работает. Удивительно, что майкрософт ничего более удобного не придумали из коробки. Ситуация вполне обычная ведь.